# Proper way to get all installed methods in Pharo

Tags: methods, reflection, pharo, idioms

Sometimes you want to analyze all the methods in the image. One way to do this is to work with `CompiledMethod allInstances`. But it is dangerous to do it this way, as

1. You may end up with old methods that were not garbage-collected yet.
2. There may be compiled methods of anonymous classes or other instances that are there for technical reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing that I came up with is:

```
RPackage organizer packages flatCollect: #methods
```

Comment: Btw the comment of that method suggests to use `RPackage organizer` instead, although I never ran into a problem with your variant.

Answer (score 2):

A dialect independent expression would be

```
ProtoObject withAllSubclasses gather: [:cls |
  cls methodDictionary values asArray,
    cls class methodDictionary values asArray]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using `SystemNavigation` which is the class designed for this:

```
SystemNavigation default allMethodsSelect: [:m | true]
```